# jQuery call not working after Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, x-editable

I have the following code to auto-open the next input field using X-Editable:

```
$('#rates .editable').on('hidden', function(e, reason){
 if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
  var $next = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.editable');

  setTimeout(function() {
   $next.editable('show');
  }, 300);
 }
});
```

It works up until an Ajax call is completed to get new rates. After that it does no longer work. I tried using Event Delegation but then it did not work at all:

```
$('#rates').on('hidden', '.editable', function(e, reason){
 if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
  var $next = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.editable');

  setTimeout(function() {
   $next.editable('show');
  }, 300);
 }
});
```

Here is the Ajax call:

```
$("#todaysrates").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'todaysrates')) %>")
```

This is how the code looks:

```
<div id="todaysrates">
 <%= render :partial => 'todaysrates' %>
</div>
```

And the partial `todaysrates` contains:

```
<table id="rates" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
....
</table>
```

Comment: Where is ajax??

Comment: Are you re-rendering any controls on `#rates` or `.editable`? You'll need to rebind the events if that's the case

Comment: Added the ajax call to the main post now @GüneySaramalı

Comment: Your second codeblock should work unless your replace/renew the `#rates` element in your ajax call or if you created `#rates` dynamically in another way. Would help if you you show the used html.

Comment: Just to clarify @MarkBaijens, the #rates is a child element of #todaysrates

Comment: @DarkKnight Does `#rates` exist on page load and is it not replaced (by Javascript  code) during it's lifespan?

Comment: you can test if it works with `$(document).on('hidden', '.editable', function(e, reason)` but only do this for testing purposes. In reality you want to replace `document` by the closest static element.

Comment: Yes it exists on page load, it does not get replaced by any code directly, only the parent element. @MarkBaijens

Comment: Tried testing with that code snippet @MarkBaijens but then it did not work at all.

Comment: @DarkKnight you say `#rates` wont get replaced. But you also say `#rates` is part of `#todaysrates` and your ajax call is using `$("#todaysrates").html()`. I got a feeling you lie about `#rates` is never replaced.

Comment: @MarkBaijens #rates does get replaced but it is not called directly via the ajax call. #todaysrates is what gets replaced by the ajax call.

Comment: Yeah but if you replace an element (Doesn't matter how) it loses their event handlers unless you use `on()` with 3 parameters. But since that doesn't even work for you when using `document` I guess you are using an old jQuery version that does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the `#rates` control as it's a child of `#todaysrates`. As a result no code is attached to the elements events as they are essentially a NEW element.

You need to rebind after your ajax.

```
$("#todaysrates").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'todaysrates')) %>")
```

And re-attach the code to fire on your hidden event...

```
$('#rates .editable').on('hidden', function(e, reason){
     if(reason === 'save' || reason === 'nochange') {
         var $next = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.editable');

         setTimeout(function() {
             $next.editable('show');
         }, 300);
     }
});
```